# axios.post Fails in App, Works in URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I'm following a React-Redux tutorial. My axios.post() is failing when running the app, but if I use that same URL and paste it into the browser's address textbox it works. Why would that happen?

Here is the call in my app:

```
const request = axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/posts/${id}${API_KEY}`);
```

Here is the error, as shown in F12 in Chrome:

> POST http://reduxblog.herokuapp.com/api/posts/120342?key=bob884 404
>   (Not Found)

Why would that fail when it's a good URL? If you click it, you'll see the response in the browser:

> {"id":120342,"title":"SOLID","categories":"OOP","content":"SOLID is an
>   acronym..."}

Comment: When clicking it, the browser performs a GET request rather than a POST request. Those are usually treated separately by the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click the link, the browser sends a `GET` request to the server.
A `POST` endpoint might not be available from the server side at that specific URL address.

Whenever the server is unable to find a URL with a specified method (`GET` / `POST`), it returns a `404 - Not found` error. In this case, it doesn't find any `POST` method defined for that address.

You should consider changing the method to a `GET` request, if that's what you desire.

Comment: That was it. I changed the axios request from post() to get() and it worked. Thanks!